# How to get a listing of WARC files using HTTP for Common Crawl News Dataset?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, common-crawl

I can obtain listing for Common Crawl by:

https://commoncrawl.s3.amazonaws.com/crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2017-09/wet.paths.gz

How can I do this with Common Crawl News Dataset ?

I tried different options, but always getting errors:

https://commoncrawl.s3.amazonaws.com/crawl-data/CC-NEWS-2017-09/warc.paths.gz

https://commoncrawl.s3.amazonaws.com/crawl-data/CC-NEWS/2017/09/warc.paths.gz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since every few hours a new WARC file is added to the news dataset, a static file list does not make sense. Instead you can get a list of files using the [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) - for any subset by year or month, e.g.

```
aws --no-sign-request s3 ls --recursive s3://commoncrawl/crawl-data/CC-NEWS/2017/09/
```

See also the [news data release announcement](https://commoncrawl.org/2016/10/news-dataset-available/).